# Como guardar una iteracion aleatoria dentro de un Array

Tags: c#, array, metodos

Ya me han ayudado con el código para poder generar matriculas aleatorias y he usado el mismo para tambien obtener (desde un array) *modelos de vehiculos aleatorios*.

Ahora quiero que dicho *vehiculo* y dicha *matricula* se almacenen en un **array**, para despues poder crear una *ficha de cliente* y que obtenga dicha *matricula* y *modelo*.

Detalle: El proyecto consiste en crear un historico de **clientes generales**, y luego, crear una **ficha historica** para uno de esos clientes, como he generado la matricula de forma aleatoria y he tomado 1 de 20 modelos de carros para asignarle esa matricula, me gustaria que el `cliente A` tuviera ese modelo de carro + la matricula proporcionada en el historico de clientes generales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso, el cliente llamado `Gustavo Serrano`, tiene un `F-Type` con su matricula, pero al momento de llamarlo en el historico de ese cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene un `Renault Clio`, por lo tanto, quería que el vehiculo correspondiera exactamente al que esta descrito en el historico general.

Este es el código que genera la matricula y modelo aleatorio, en conjunto con un orden de los nombres dentro de un Array:

```
namespace Prueba2C_Projeto
{
    internal class Matricula
    {
        public static string Matriculas()
        {
        // Nomes das Pessoas Inscritas
            string[] nomes = new string[] { "Diana Cazorla", "Yasmina Matas", 
                "Kevin Pujol", "Armando Freitas", "Rómario Asnard", "Juan Dos 
                Santos", "Carlina Valera", "Gustavo Serrano", "Alvaro 
                Castillo", "António Fernández", "João Pereira", "Herminia 
                Meneses", "Francisco Moço", "Eloi Royo", "Santiago Márques" };

            for(int i = 0; i < nomes.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID  NOMBRE E APELIDO      VIATURA E 
                 MATRÍCULA" + "\n");
                foreach (string nome in nomes)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"{getId()}. {nome}      
                      {Viatura.getViatura()} [{getMatricula()}]");
                    i++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"\n" + $"Existem um total de {i} Clientes registados en Base de Datos");
        }

        return "";
    }

    
    
    public static string getMatricula()
    {
        string matriculaRandom = String.Empty;
        

        Random randomChar = new Random();
        char[] letras = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        matriculaRandom = randomChar.Next(10, 99) + "-" + letras[randomChar.Next(26)].ToString() + letras[randomChar.Next(26)].ToString() + "-" + randomChar.Next(10, 99);


        return matriculaRandom;
    }

    public static string getId()
    {
        string idRandom = String.Empty;
        Random randomId = new Random();
        char[] letras = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };
        
        idRandom = letras[randomId.Next(26)].ToString() + randomId.Next(1, 9);

        return idRandom;
    }




}
```

}

Y este es el historico que se refleja luego:

```
namespace Prueba2C_Projeto.AreaCliente
{
    internal class Cliente
    {
        public static string VerHistoricoCliente()
        {
            // Dados do Cliente
            Console.WriteLine(" < -- OS TEUS DADOS -- > " + "\n");

            Console.WriteLine("NOME E APELIDO: " + "Gustavo Serrano");
            Console.WriteLine("NIF: '1563513'");
            Console.WriteLine("B.I: '185JK6S15" + "\n");

            Console.WriteLine($"VIATURA: '{Viatura.getViatura()}'");
            Console.WriteLine($"MATRÍCULA: '{Matricula.getMatricula()}'" + 
               "\n");

            // Criação da Data presente a partir da data de criação do Sistema 
            // do Primer Parquímetro
            DateTime dataInicial = new DateTime(2017, 4, 14);
            Random random = new Random();
            // Função que vai ter uma data qualquer entre 2017 e 2023
            int intervaloDias = (DateTime.Today - dataInicial).Days;
            DateTime dataRandom = dataInicial.AddDays(random.Next(intervaloDias)); // Output da data qualquer entre 
              // o invertalos
                                                                               
             // Função para obter os dias desde a primera e ultima data
            DateTime dataActual = DateTime.Today;
            TimeSpan difDatas = dataRandom - dataActual;
            int dias = difDatas.Days; // Só obter os dias

            // Output dos elementos
            Console.WriteLine($"Data de registo: 
            {dataRandom.ToShortDateString()}"); // ToShortDateString() para 
             // não imprimir as horas, minutos, segundos
            Console.WriteLine($"Estás registado há {dias * -1} días" + "\n");

            return "";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: Hola bianchi, el problema es que al colocar en la seccion del historico de cliente el vehiculo, siempre va a cambiar y no se mantendra como en el historico de clientes en general

Comment: Eso que decis, no se donde esta en toda esta maraña de codigo.. si explicas mejor, podemos ayudarte mejor... no se porque decis lo que decis, tenes que explicarnoslo en tu codigo...

Comment: Si no guardas los datos de matrícula, id, nombre, etc en una instancia de una clase o un array global u alguna otra forma, cómo esperas luego obtenerlos en otra clase diferente?